# Problems using split view controllers in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm new at objective-c programming and I need help clearing some doubts about the split view controllers. I understand that if you use a split view controller in your app then it must necessarily be your root view and I was wondering if there was any way to get around it.

I mean, I need to use split view controllers in my app but only in a couple of views, and for the rest just use simple views. If anyone has any idea or suggestion as to how to do this I'd be really grateful.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you can do. You can present your simple views modally, which will cover up the split view controller, or you can switch out the window's root view controller when you're done with the split view. Which to do depends on how and where in your app you use the split view. If you are going back and forth to it, then I would use the first method, if you're using it once, then going to the simple views, I would use the second method.

Answer (score 0):

You can add split view controllers as children of tabbarviewcontrollers. Also, you can add split view controllers into [container view controllers you build](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html).

Comment: This might be possible, but according to Apple's docs, "A split view controller must always be the root of any interface you create."

Comment: My comment is not a conjecture. I have several apps on iTunes. See the iPad tab screenshots on iTunes for https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/isabi-spanish-p/id591189716?mt=8. There are a number of apps that have done similar things.

Comment: Do your apps have split view controllers that are not the root view (I would like to know if Apple allows it)? I've built apps that look like the one in your link using a custom controller that looks like a split view controller so you can't really tell from looking at an app if it has a non-root split view controller. I assume Apple has a reason for saying the split view controller must be the root view controller, so even if it works now to have it not be so, there might be unintended consequences if they change something.

Comment: For our apps, the tabbarviewcontroller is Installed directly as a window’s root view controller. Then each tab can be a splitviewcontroller or some other view controller. We created the controllers for the tabbarviewcontroller programmatically.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. Yeah, I noticed that Xcode doesn't let you embed a UISplitViewController in a tab bar controller (in the storyboard with the menu command), but that it can be done in code, as you say.